# Why aren't my col-lg- shown full width?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

After getting some help with [alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738304/how-to-align-elements-in-a-bootstrap-form) of my controls, I'm now struggling to fully understand, exploit and adopt that solution.

The current state of affairs can be played with [here](http://www.bootply.com/4DCKUvoroW#) and the code is below:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="form-inline col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">     
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></span></div>
          <input id="oldpswd" name="oldpswd" placeholder="Altes Passwort" type="password" class="form-control">   
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <span id="oldpswd_errmsg" class="bg-danger col-lg-4">xxxx</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="form-inline col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">     
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></span></div>
          <input id="oldpswd" name="newpswd" placeholder="Neues Passwort" type="password" class="form-control">   
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <span id="newpswd_errmsg" class="bg-danger col-lg-4">xxxx</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="form-inline col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">     
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></span></div>
          <input id="reppswd" name="reppswd" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" type="password" class="form-control">   
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <span id="reppswd_errmsg" class="bg-danger col-lg-4">xxxx</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Question: within the row there is a `col-lg-8` that contains two `col-lg-4` divs. As I understood the doc, the input-controls are supposed to take up the entire width of their containers, yet the form-group inside the `col-lg-4` is significantly smaller than its container.

How can this layout be fixed so that the divs with designated `col-lg-` classes use the available space?

Comment: I Wish you could have provided CSS too

Comment: Use col-lg-6 instead of col-lg-4

Comment: @captainsac: sry, the CSS is the standard bootstrap-CSS as you can see @ bootply (my link "here")

Comment: @user3756181: but 4+4 is 8, so mathematically at least that should match. Or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated

Addedd css to expand the form controls to expand with divs.

Is this what you want? http://www.bootply.com/y2K2OY8H1H

You had a row, with a column of 8, with two columns of 4 inside that. So the col-8 fills 8 of the 12 main columns. Then the 2 col-4 inside of that only fill 8 of the 12 inside that col-8. So each time you nest the col's you create nested columns. It is a little confusing, but makes sense.

NEW CSS:

```
   .form-group {
     width:100%;
   }

  .input-group {
     width:100%; 
   }
```

-

```
  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></span></div>
                    <input id="oldpswd" name="oldpswd" placeholder="Altes Passwort" type="password" class="form-control">   
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <span id="oldpswd_errmsg" class="bg-danger col-lg-3">xxxx</span>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></span></div>
                    <input id="oldpswd" name="newpswd" placeholder="Neues Passwort" type="password" class="form-control">   
            </div></div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <span id="newpswd_errmsg" class="bg-danger col-lg-3">xxxx</span>

</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></span></div>
                    <input id="reppswd" name="reppswd" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" type="password" class="form-control">   
            </div></div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <span id="reppswd_errmsg" class="bg-danger col-lg-3">xxxx</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, it isn't. Look at the first div: it has col-lg-3, the same as the red errmsg. So it should also be shown with that width and should not have such a large space between the two divs!

Comment: Bootstrap columns do not just resize to to the content inside them. They are percentage widths. So if you set it to col-lg-6 the width would be 50%. If you want the two divs to size specifically you need to use your own css.

Comment: @MBaas take a look now.

Comment: I did not expect the columns to resize to the content inside of them, but I expected the content to resize to the columns.   At http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php  I read this "You can also match the sizes of your form controls to the Bootstrap grid column sizes. Just wrap your form controls (i.e. <input>, <textarea>, and <select>) in grid columns, or any custom element and apply the grid classes on it.", so I thought the input should stretch to the full width of the container...

Comment: Ok, I have it expanding to the width of the col now take a look.